# How Can I set the Stopwatch Name in runtime?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, timer, addition, stopwatch

I need a solution for a small problem in my project and I'll make it as simple as possible:

At one of the forms in my project, user should be able to add a panel to the form and that form should contain 2 controls ... a label and a (stopwatch or timer).

The problem is after creating the stopwatch dynamically, I can't set a name for the stopwatch. Later in that form when user clicks on the panel stopwatch must start. How can I set the name for created stopwatch? or any other solution if my way is too stupid. Here's what I have :

```
Dim Panels As Integer = ds.Tables("Pool").Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To Panels 
            'set the new panel number
            Dim NextPanelNumber As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count + 1
            'controls to be added
            Dim NextPanel As New PanelControl
            Dim NextPanelLabel As New LabelControl
            Dim NextPanelStopwatch As New Stopwatch
            'determine properties for new table
            NextPanel.Width = 200
            NextPanel.Height = 114
            NextPanelStopwatch.Name = "anything" ' <-- PROBLEM IS HERE

            'add controls into new panel
            NextPanel.Controls.Add(NextPanelLabel)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should create a user control that contains a label and a stopwatch. Simply expose the properties you need to customize and add those to a flow layout panel?

Comment: Yes, it is already being added to a flowlayoutpanel but what I'm struggling with is setting the name of the stopwatch ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

You created the name for the Stopwatch when you created it, there is not an additional name property. Just make sure that the instance has visibility where you want to start at.

```
Dim NextPanelStopWatch As New Stopwatch
NextPanelStopWatch.Start()
```

Comment: Ok let's say I have 3 stopwatches with these names : NextPanelStopWatch1, NextPanelStopWatch2, NextPanelStopWatch3 ... If I click on panel 1 I want the first stopwatch to start. How do I call it then ?

Comment: I see what your problem is, what you are trying to do is cumbersome, what your best bet would be is to create a usercontrol and expose the methods you need from there. What you are needing is an unique class scoped variable for each stopwatch which you don't have since your are creating it in a loop. You can try creating a Class scoped List(Of Stopwatch) and add your Stopwatches to it then you could call them by instance. i.e. StopWatchList(1).Start. You are going to have the same issue with other items as well.